# Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain the text node "Home" in <div>

Tags: reactjs, npm, next.js, package, tsdx

We are making an npm react package (by tsdx library) which is a custom hook. Developers who install this package need to make a ***config.json*** file at the root and a ***Languages.json*** file in the public folder of their Next.js project. We need to access the information in these files that the developer wrote.

Package files:

***LanguageProvider.tsx***: A react context that stores the current locale state.

***UseTranslation.tsx***: A custom hook that gets the locale from the context and finds the key from the current locale in Languages.json.

```js
export function useTranslation() {
  const { locale } = useContext(LanguageContext);
  let LanguagesFile;
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    const fs = require('fs');
    LanguagesFile = fs.readFileSync("./public/Languages.json", 'utf8');
  }
  
  function t(key: string) {
    if (typeof LanguagesFile !== 'undefined') {
      const Languages = JSON.parse(LanguagesFile);
      if (!Languages && !Languages[locale] && !Languages[locale][key]) {
        console.warn(`No string '${key}' for locale '${locale}'`);
        return false;
      } else {
        return Languages[locale][key].toString() || '';
      }
    }
  }
  return t;
}
```

***package.json***

```json
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "typings": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsdx watch",
    "build": "tsdx build",
    "test": "tsdx test --passWithNoTests",
    "lint": "tsdx lint",
    "prepare": "tsdx build",
    "size": "size-limit",
    "analyze": "size-limit --why"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": ">=16"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "tsdx lint"
    }
  },
  "prettier": {
    "printWidth": 80,
    "semi": true,
    "singleQuote": true,
    "trailingComma": "es5"
  },
  "name": "react-intl",
  "author": "Roya Shahroudi",
  "module": "dist/react-intl.esm.js",
  "size-limit": [
    {
      "path": "dist/react-intl.cjs.production.min.js",
      "limit": "10 KB"
    },
    {
      "path": "dist/react-intl.esm.js",
      "limit": "10 KB"
    }
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@size-limit/preset-small-lib": "^5.0.4",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.22",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "husky": "^7.0.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "size-limit": "^5.0.4",
    "tsdx": "^0.14.1",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "typescript": "^4.4.3"
  }
}
```

The Next.js project that installed this package:

***public/Languages.json***

```json
{
    "en-us": {
        "home": "Home",
        "about": "About us"
    },
    "fa-ir": {
        "home": "خانه",
        "about": "درباره ما"
    }
}
```

***pages/index.js***

```js
export default function Home({Languages}) {
  const { locale, setLang } = useContext(LanguageContext);
  const t = useTranslation();

  return (
    <>
      <div>{t('home')}</div>
      <button onClick={() => setLang('fa-ir')}>
        Change Language To Persian
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setLang('en-us')}>
        Change Language To English
      </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

When I run the project it shows this warning in the browser console:

```
Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain the text node "Home" in <div>.
    at div
    at Home
```

and the text from ***t*** function doesn’t render on the page.

Comment: `LanguagesFile` will be undefined on the client-side because you're only reading the languages file on the server. Meaning that when `t()` is called on the client it'll return undefined, and nothing will get rendered.

Comment: Thank you @juliomalves, we already knew this but we don't know how to send it to the client-side.