# How to read files on the client-side not only on server side?

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-hooks, next.js, tsdx

We are making an npm react package (by tsdx library), a custom hook for multi-languaging react projects.
Developers who install this package need to make a ***config.json*** file at the root and a ***Languages.json*** file in the public folder of their Next.js project. What we need is that we can read ***Languages.json*** on the client-side of the app.

Package files:
***LanguageProvider.tsx***: A react context that stores the current locale state.

***UseTranslation.tsx***: A custom hook that gets the locale from the context and finds the key from the same locale in Languages.json.

```js
export function useTranslation() {
  const { locale } = useContext(LanguageContext);
  let LanguagesFile;
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    const fs = require('fs');
    LanguagesFile = fs.readFileSync("./public/Languages.json", 'utf8');
  }
  
  function t(key: string) {
    if (typeof LanguagesFile !== 'undefined') {
      const Languages = JSON.parse(LanguagesFile);
      if (!Languages && !Languages[locale] && !Languages[locale][key]) {
        console.warn(`No string '${key}' for locale '${locale}'`);
        return false;
      } else {
        return Languages[locale][key].toString() || '';
      }
    }
  }
  return t;
}
```

When I log ***Languages.json*** file from ***UseTranslation.tsx***, it shows me the data on the server, but it is undefined on the client-side of the app.

Comment: Why not store the languages as object instead json, and then regular `import` instead of `fs.readFileSync`?

Comment: Isn't this the same problem as [Warning: Did not expect server HTML to contain the text node "Home" in <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69515500/warning-did-not-expect-server-html-to-contain-the-text-node-home-in-div)?